# Can this equation with multiple radicals be solved using closed form expressions?

Tags: radicals, closed-form, radical-equations

For an expression of the following form:

$\frac{f(x) + \sqrt{ g(x)}}{h(x)} = \frac{k(x) + \sqrt{ l(x)}}{m(x)} $,

where $f(x)$, $g(x)$, $h(x)$, $k(x)$, $l(x)$ and $m(x)$ are all quadratics and where the descriminants of $l(x)$ and $g(x)$ are not equal to zero in general, is it possible to simplify this expression to a quartic in x (i.e. order 4 or lower)?

My attempts so far always involve isolating a radical on one side of the equation squaring both sides and simplifying. This results in significant "order bloat", meaning the equation can no longer be solved analytically (i.e. order 5 or above). I am wondering if there is some handy trick that may be performed to avoid this.

In response to a comment asking for the whole expression:

$\frac{a_1x^2 + a_2x + a_3 + \sqrt{ a_4x^2 + a_5x + a_6}}{a_7x^2 + a_8x + a_9} = \frac{a_{10}x^2 + a_{11}x + a_{12} + \sqrt{ a_{13}x^2 + a_{14}x + a_{15}}}{a_{16}x^2 + a_{17}x + a_{18}} $

where $a_{1:18}$ are constants. I'd like to solve for $x$.

It was requested in a comment that I give some context to this question. I am solving an engineering/software problem to do with finding diffracted paths in ray-tracing simulations for radio propagation. I was trying to find a closed-form expression for the points on two arbitrary lines in 3D space, A and B, such that the path from a transmitter point T to A to B to a receiver point R is a short as possible. Writing an expression for the total length of this path and then taking partial derivatives, first with respect to a scaling variable that adjusts the position of A on its line and also with respect to another scaling variable that adjusts the position of B on its line, and setting each to zero gives two equations with two unknowns. After simplifying I ended up with an expression in the form of that posed in the question. Efficient numerical techniques already exist for multiple lines, I wanted to see if I could do a closed form for just two.

Comment: Can you write down the whole expression please?

Comment: Do you mean $$\frac{ax^2+bx+c+\sqrt{dx^2+ex+f}}{gx^2+hx+i}=\frac{kx^2+lx+m+\sqrt{ox^2+px+q}}{rx^2+sx+t}$$where all numbers are real

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question to indicate this.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner And the polynomials under radicals are not squares.

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: You would like to solve this for $x$?

Comment: Yes, so the question now says.

Comment: Hm, i will try it.

Comment: Belated request for clarification: are you perhaps only interested in real values of $x$ such that $g(x) \geqslant 0$ and $l(x) \geqslant 0$? In that case, are the square root expressions allowed to take negative values, or not? On the other hand, if more general values of $x$ are permitted, then how are the square root signs to be interpreted? Whatever the answers to these questions, the answer I have posted will need to be reconsidered; but without the needed clarifications, it may not be possible to proceed, unless I can think of a simple modification of my argument using only real numbers.

Comment: Also, the question in the title of the question (if you see what I mean!) differs from the question in the body of the question. I've answered the latter (I think), but might it be the former, more general question that is of more interest to you? That is, are you interested in *any* closed-form solutions, even if they cannot be obtained from the general solutions of quartic (and lower degree) polynomial equations?

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley , both $g(x)$ and $l(x)$ are positive valued regardless of the value of x positive or negative, however, for the actual problem that I'm working on, $x$ may not be negative. If this helps then please use that fact, if it doesn't then ignore it and I can post-process solutions. I am only interested in real values of $x$. As you suggest, I am interested in any closed-form solutions (as in the title), not just those found using solutions to polynomials. I was foolish not to allow the possibility of finding closed-form solutions another way.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Just to make quite sure: $\sqrt{g(x)}$ and $\sqrt{l(x)}$ denote, as usual, the non-negative square roots of $g(x)$ and $l(x)$?

Comment: Correct. $g(x)$ and $l(x)$ are positive and real for any real value of $x$ and the sqrt is the non-negative square root. $x$ is real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, on the assumption that any process of "simplification" will yield a polynomial in $x$ with rational coefficients if the coefficients of the given quadratics are rational.

Consider any case where $h(x) = m(x)$ and $f(x) = 0$.

If $x$ satisfies the given equation, then
$$
\sqrt{g(x)} - \sqrt{l(x)} = k(x)
$$
and therefore
$$
\tag{$*$}\label{eq:1}
4g(x)l(x) = (k(x)^2 - g(x) - l(x))^2.
$$
Now specialise further, to the case:
\begin{align*}
g(x) & = x^2 + \tfrac12, \\
l(x) & = x^2 - \tfrac12, \\
k(x) & = x^2 + 1.
\end{align*}
\eqref{eq:1} becomes
$$
4x^4 - 1 = (x^4 + 1)^2.
$$
This can be solved explicitly in terms of nested square roots, but it is enough for our purposes to rewrite it as
$$
x^8 - 2x^4 + 2 = 0,
$$
and observe that by Eisenstein's criterion the polynomial on the left hand side is irreducible over the rationals, therefore $x$ does not satisfy any polynomial equation of degree less than $8$ with rational coefficients.

### Update

This uses a second example to answer the question of whether reduction to a quartic equation is possible. It takes into account the clarification of the question in comments made since this answer was first posted. A further update below uses a third example to answer the more general question asked in the title of the thread: does the equation have an [algebraic solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_solution)
(which might not be obtained by reduction to a quartic)?

Consider the special case
$$
\frac{x^2 + 1 + \sqrt{x^2 + x + \tfrac12}}{x^2 + 1} =
\frac{2x^2 + \sqrt{x^2 - x + \tfrac12}}{x^2 + 1}.
$$
Here we have
\begin{align*}
g(x) & = x^2 + x + \tfrac12 =
\left(x + \tfrac12\right)^2 + \tfrac14 > 0, \\
l(x) & = x^2 - x + \tfrac12 =
\left(x - \tfrac12\right)^2 + \tfrac14 > 0,
\end{align*}
for all  real $x$, so the stated conditions are satisfied.  The
equation simplifies to
\begin{equation}
\tag{$**$}\label{3380555:eq:2}
\sqrt{g(x)} - \sqrt{l(x)} = n(x),
\end{equation}
where $n(x) = x^2 - 1$. The four equations
$$
\pm\sqrt{g(x)} \pm\sqrt{l(x)} = n(x)
$$
together are equivalent to a single polynomial equation
$$
4g(x)l(x) = (n(x)^2 - g(x) - l(x))^2.
$$
Because
$g(x)l(x) = \left(x^2 + \tfrac12\right)^2 - x^2 = x^4 + \tfrac14$,
and $g(x) + l(x) = 2x^2 + 1$, the polynomial equation reduces to
$$
4x^4 + 1 = (x^4 - 4x^2)^2,
$$
i.e. $p(x) = 0$, where
$$
p(x) = x^8 - 8x^6 + 12x^4 - 1.
$$
Write this as $p(x) = q(x^2)$, where
$q(y) = y^4 - 8y^3 + 12y^2 - 1 = y^2(y - 2)(y - 6) - 1$.
$$
\begin{array}{r|rrrrrr}
  y  & -1 &  0 & 1 &  2 &  6 &  7 \\
q(y) & 20 & -1 & 4 & -1 & -1 & 244
\end{array}
$$
$p(x)$ therefore has six real roots and two imaginary roots.
Corresponding to the root of $q(y)$ just below $2$, $p(x)$ has the
real root
$$
x \bumpeq 1.390776704210124
$$
(as calculated in Python using Newton's method).

Numerical calculation confirms that this value of $x$ is also a
solution of \eqref{3380555:eq:2}. (A comment below shows that this is the only positive solution.)

I didn't have the heart to try to solve the quartic equation
$q(y) = 0$ to obtain a closed-form expression for $x$ and try to use
it to prove that \eqref{3380555:eq:2} is satisfied!
Instead one can prove it by using inequalities.  We have
$1 < x^2 < 2$, therefore $0 < n(x) < 1$. Also $g(x) > l(x)$, so we
cannot have $-\sqrt{g(x)} \pm\sqrt{l(x)} = n(x)$.
Next, $\sqrt{g(x)} > x + \tfrac12$ and $\sqrt{l(x)} > x - \tfrac12$,
so $\sqrt{g(x)} + \sqrt{l(x)} > 2x > 2 > n(x)$.
Now only \eqref{3380555:eq:2} remains as a possibility.

We have $p(X) \equiv X^8 + X^6 + 2 \pmod3$, and the latter
polynomial is listed as being irreducible on this web site:
[Irreducible trinomials over GF(3)](http://fchabaud.free.fr/English/default.php?COUNT=3&FILE0=Poly&FILE1=GF(3)&FILE2=Trinomials).
I take this to be good evidence that $p(x)$ is irreducible, although
I haven't verified the result stated on the web site. It follows as
before that $x$ does not satisfy any polynomial equation of degree
less than $8$ with rational coefficients.

### Update 2

Consider the special case
$$
\frac{x^2 + 2 + \sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}}{x^2 + 2} =
\frac{x^2 + 1 + \sqrt{x^2 - x + 1}}{x^2 + 1}.
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
(x^2 + 1)\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} = (x^2 + 2)\sqrt{x^2 - x + 1}.
$$
Because both sides of the latter equation are positive, it is in turn equivalent, for real $x$, to the polynomial equation
$$
(x^2 + 1)^2(x^2 + x + 1) = (x^2 + 2)^2(x^2 - x + 1).
$$
Simplifying:
$$
x[(x^2 + 1)^2 + (x^2 + 2)^2] = (x^2 + 1)[(x^2 + 2)^2 - (x^2 + 1)^2].
$$
This equation simplifies in turn to the quintic equation $p(x) = 0$, where
$$
p(x) = 2x^5 - 2x^4 + 6x^3 - 5x^2 + 5x - 3.
$$
$p'''(x) = 120x^2 - 48x + 36 = 120\left(x-\tfrac15\right)^2 + 31\tfrac15 > 0$
for all $x$, so the cubic $p''(x)$ is strictly increasing. Its unique zero is
$x_0 \bumpeq 0.30861$. But $p'(x_0) \bumpeq 3.4838$, therefore $p'(x) > 0$ for
all $x$, therefore $p(x)$ is strictly increasing, therefore it has a unique real zero:
$$
x \bumpeq 0.705526664475018.
$$
We have $3p(X) \equiv X^5 + 4X^4 + 3X^3 + 1 \pmod{5}$, which is listed as irreducible [here](http://fchabaud.free.fr/English/Poly/randomform.php?FDeg=5&LDeg=1&Output=HGF%285%29%2FExhaustive), implying that $p(X)$ is irreducible in
$\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

According to [GAP 4.8.10](http://www.gap-system.org/):

```
gap> GaloisType(UnivariatePolynomial(Rationals,[-3,5,-5,6,-2,2]));
5
gap> TransitiveGroup(5,5);
S5
```

I think this proves that the Galois group of $p(X)$ is isomorphic to $S_5$. This group is famously not solvable. Therefore, no root of $p(X)$, including its unique real root shown above, is given by an expression involving only integer constants, field operations, and/or extractions of roots.

It follows that the general equation
$$
\frac{f(x) + \sqrt{ g(x)}}{h(x)} = \frac{k(x) + \sqrt{ l(x)}}{m(x)}
$$
has no general solution expressed in terms of field operations, extractions of roots, and the coefficients of $f, g, h, k, l, m$.

Comment: I'm interested in the solution using nested square roots. I'd never heard of Eisenstein. I will look him up.

Comment: From $(x^4 - 1)^2 = -1$, i.e. $x^4 = 1 \pm i$, one gets $x/\sqrt[8]{2} \in
\{\pm\omega, \pm\bar{\omega}, \pm i\omega, \pm i\bar{\omega}\}$,
where
$$
\omega = e^{\frac{i\pi}{16}} = \frac12\left(
\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}} +
i\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}\right).
$$
I didn't bother to check which of these eight values satisfy the
original equation, nor did I bother to derive the expression for
$e^{\frac{i\pi}{16}}$ myself.

Comment: I have added clarification in the comments on the original question. I am interested in any closed-form expressions.

Comment: In the update, I also meant to point out that $x \bumpeq 1.39$ is the only real solution of \eqref{3380555:eq:2}, because $\sqrt{g(x)} < x + \tfrac58$ and $\sqrt{l(x)} < x - \tfrac38$, therefore $\tfrac78 < n(x) < \tfrac98$, i.e. $1\tfrac78 < x^2 < 2\tfrac18$.

Comment: **Correction:** that is the only *positive* solution. (If $x > 0$, then $g(x) > l(x)$, therefore $x^2 - 1 > 0$, i.e. $x > 1$, and the rest of the argument is valid, I think.) But $-0.569432366456002$ is also a solution. (It's past my bedtime again. I'll tidy these comments up tomorrow.)

Comment: Heroic answer. Thanks for all your help. Am I correct in understanding that this special case is made to be deliberately 'nice', such that the result that it doesn't reduce beyond degree 8 will be generally true for any choice of coefficients for the different polynomials? I'm also intrigued by the statement '.... with rational coefficients'. Does this mean it could be done with irrational coefficients?

Comment: To the second question: maybe.  I feel it's unlikely, but it would better to have a rigorous proof of impossibility.  To the first question: yes and no.  I chose the special case to be 'nice' enough that I could prove something about it, but 'nasty' enough not to reduce to a quartic.  Some special cases do reduce to quartics, e.g. those where $fm = hk$ and $h$ and $m$ have a common linear factor.

Comment: (I'm sorry about the flurry of comments. I'll try to absorb the useful points into a second update, eventually. We already appear to have all of the ingredients for a full answer to the question in the title, but I want to check the argument, minimising dependence on software.) $p'''(x) = 120x^2 - 48x + 36 = 120\left(x-\tfrac15\right)^2 + 31\tfrac15 > 0$ for all $x$, so the cubic $p''(x)$ is strictly increasing. Its unique zero is $x_0 \bumpeq 0.30861$. But $p'(x_0) \bumpeq 3.4838$, therefore $p'(x) > 0$ for all $x$, therefore $p(x)$ is strictly increasing, therefore it has a unique real zero.

Comment: No problem :) fascinating.

Comment: My understanding of Galois theory (and group theory generally) is embarrassingly tenuous, but I'll try to swot up on using GAP (which I had never used before yesterday), to see if I can work out an at least partly "manual" or "human" proof.

Comment: All I can say is that I'm super impressed. Alas, your answer shows my battleship has sunk, I have accepted your very good answer and would like to thank you for all your help.

Comment: Thank you. Without raising your hopes too much, I'd encourage you to
keep some scepticism in reserve, especially in view of my lack of
expertise, and my dependence on some unfamiliar software.

I'm quite curious as to how the question arose. Would it be possible
to say something about this, in a comment on the question, or an
addition to the question itself? (It's not essential. The question
stands well on its own. I'd like to add that I had felt scarcely a
flicker of interest in mathematics for months, but this question
really piqued my curiosity - so you've done me quite a favour!)

Comment: I have updated the question. I'm glad it gave you something to get your teeth stuck into! I was in a bit of a research rut until I found this little problem. Weirdly engaging.

Answer (score 0):

I'll omit the '$(x)$' notation for brevity.

$$fm+m\sqrt q=hk+h\sqrt l$$
$$m\sqrt q=F+h\sqrt l,\text{, where }\deg F=4$$
$$m^2q=F^2+2hF\sqrt l+h^2l$$
$$G=2hF\sqrt l\text{, where }\deg G=8$$
so you can get degree $16$ at last.

This is really not a proof, 
because I haven't proved that that degree is actually reached, but my feeling is that it can.

If you want a real proof, you should test with random polynomials and a good software. If you get a equation with more than $4$ solutions, you are done.

*Remark*: You should put positive polynomials (that is, $\Delta<0$ and main coef.$>0$) under radicals to avoid complex roots. Also you should balance numerators and denominators to void thad some side is much bigger than the other.

Comment: So this mirrors my previous attempts. The way you have phrased your answer makes it seem like you have interpreted my question as wanting as high an order expression as possible, in reality, I want one as low as possible. It might be that your answer is just what the expression is, which seems likely, in which case I have my answer, but I was hoping this wasn't the case, hence my question.